# swift - arrange buttons across many screens

Tags: swift, user-interface

I develop test app with swift , 
I need way to arrange first row in first screen to first row in second screen

to make all button across application look similar 
my tries :

match X,Y value , width , height

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Auto Layout ?

You can achieve that by

1. set vertical space between the top edge and your title
2. set horizontal alignment of title to be center of the view
3. set vertical space between title and the first item in the row
4. set leading margin of the first item in the first row
5. set horizontal alignment of all following items to be center of the first item